# How can we make jest wait for an event before making an assert?

Tags: javascript, typescript, events, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm creating a façade for the nats streaming lib as follows:

```
import nats, { Message, Stan, Subscription, SubscriptionOptions } from 'node-nats-streaming'

class NatsHelper {
  private client: Stan | null = null

  public connect(url: string, clusterID: string, clientID: string, listener: (...args: any[]) => void, verboseConnection: boolean = true): void {
    const clientIDString = `${clientID}-${randomBytes(4).toString('hex')}`
    if (verboseConnection) {
      console.log(`Connecting to NATS cluster '${clusterID}' with clientID '${clientIDString}' on url '${url}'`)
    }
    const connectionAttempt = nats.connect(
      clusterID,
      clientIDString,
      {
        url
      }
    )

    const setupConnection = (...args: any[]): void => {
      this.client = connectionAttempt

      this.client.on('close', (): void => {
        if (verboseConnection) {
          console.log(`Connection with NATS cluster '${clusterID}' with clientID '${clientIDString}' on url '${url}' was closed`)
        }
        this.client = null
        process.exit()
      })

      process.on('SIGINT', () => this.client?.close())
      process.on('SIGTERM', () => this.client?.close())

      if (verboseConnection) {
        console.log(`Connected to NATS cluster '${clusterID}' with clientID '${clientIDString}' on url '${url}' successfuly`)
      }
      listener(...args)
    }

    connectionAttempt.on('connect', setupConnection)
  }
}
```

It happens though that I'm not able to test if the provided listener function is called, because it relies on the Stan 'connect' event to happen and jest finishes the test before it happens.

How can I make jest wait for this event to happen, and then executes the expect function?

Comment: Can you post the test files that you have tried?

Comment: I added an answer with what I've came with. There wasn't much I could do to force the event to happen, because jest doesn't support features like waiting for an event to happen once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overcomplicated this. It's perfectly possible to write the test for the original code without modifying it by mocking out the library using `jest.mock()`, and injecting mock implementations for your on method. Like this:

```
import nats from "node-nats-streaming";
import { mock } from "jest-mock-extended";
import { NatsHelper } from "./nats";

jest.mock("node-nats-streaming");

describe("NatsHelper", () => {
  it("calls listener on connectEvent", () => {
    const client = mock<nats.Stan>();

    client.on.mockImplementation((name, callback) => {
      if (name !== "close") {
        callback();
      }
      return client;
    });

    jest.mocked(nats).connect.mockReturnValue(client);

    const connector = new NatsHelper();

    const listener = jest.fn();

    connector.connect("foo", "foo", "foo", listener);

    expect(listener).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Were you intending to test it originally without mocking out the library? Because I'm fairly sure that's possible too, if you have connection details that will actually work with this library.

Comment: Hello Ben Wainwright, thanks for your time. Yeah, I agree that I've overcomplicated the problem. As I'm testing a façade, I have to test the interaction between my façade and the lib. It happens that the way I found for it to work was to convert an event into a promise.

Comment: You were right the whole time . Thanks sharing the expertise Ben Wainwright

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] Found the solution I was looking
It happens that we can "convert" an event into a Promise, as follows:

```
import { randomBytes } from 'crypto'
import nats from 'node-nats-streaming'

export class NullClientError extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super('Nats client is not connected')
    this.name = 'NullClientError'
  }
}

export class NatsHelper {
  private verboseConnectionString: string
  private client: nats.Stan
  private connector: nats.Stan

  constructor(
    private readonly verboseConnection: boolean = true
  ) { }

  public async connect(url: string, clusterID: string, clientID: string, callback: (...args: any[]) => void): Promise<void> {
    const clientIDString = `${clientID}-${randomBytes(4).toString('hex')}`
    this.verboseConnectionString = `NATS cluster '${clusterID}' with clientID '${clientIDString}' on url '${url}'`
    if (this.verboseConnection) {
      console.log(`Connecting to ${this.verboseConnectionString}`)
    }

    this.connector = nats.connect(
      clusterID,
      clientIDString,
      {
        url
      }
    )

    this.connector.on('connect', (...args: any[]) => {
      const realCallback = this.setupListener(callback)
      realCallback(...args)
    })

    return await new Promise(
      resolve => {
        if (this.connector) {
          this.connector.on('connect', () => {
            resolve()
          })
        }
      }
    )
  }

  private setupListener(listener: (...args: any[]) => void): (...args: any[]) => void {
    const setupConnection = (...args: any[]): void => {
      if (this.connector === undefined) {
        throw new NullClientError()
      }

      this.client = this.connector

      if (this.client === undefined) {
        throw new NullClientError()
      }

      this.client.on('close', (): void => {
        if (this.verboseConnection) {
          console.log(`Connection with ${this.verboseConnectionString} was closed`)
        }
        process.exit()
      })

      process.on('SIGINT', () => this.client?.close())
      process.on('SIGTERM', () => this.client?.close())

      if (this.verboseConnection) {
        console.log(`Connected to ${this.verboseConnectionString} successfuly`)
      }
      listener(...args)
    }
    return setupConnection
  }
}
```

And then test it with asynchronous tests:

```
describe('NatsHelper', () => {
  test('ensure NatsHelper calls connect with correct values', async () => {
    const connectSpy = jest.spyOn(nats, 'connect')
    const sut = new NatsHelper(false)
    const { url, clusterID, clientID, listener } = makeConnectionParams()
    await sut.connect(url, clusterID, clientID, listener)
    const clientIDString = connectSpy.mock.calls[0][1]
    expect(clientIDString).toContain(clientID)
    expect(connectSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(clusterID, clientIDString, { url })
  })

  test('ensure NatsHelper forwards the callback when connected', async () => {
    const connectionParms = makeConnectionParams()
    const { url, clusterID, clientID } = connectionParms
    const listenerSpy = jest.spyOn(connectionParms, 'listener')
    const sut = new NatsHelper(false)
    await sut.connect(url, clusterID, clientID, connectionParms.listener)
    expect(listenerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
}
```